# Reporting tool with angular 5 and .net Core 2

Tags: reporting, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to build my first application using angular 5 and .NET core 2; The application is created in visual studio 2017 as one empty website based on .Net core 2; I am using angular 5 for the client-side, and to maintain data-access, security, authorization ... I am creating Web API controllers using .Net core 2 which will be called from angular; What I still don't know is how to create reports which requirements are the below:

1. Reports are textual and they can contain sub-reports or images;
2. They should be created in server side as **some of them** should
   be saved on the webserver
3. They should be exported as images or PDF files
4. They should be also displayed on HTML page **whether they were saved or not** on the webserver: so there should be a way to revert back to angular 5 and display those reports on the browser
5. Please note that I have no SQL Database but Oracle 11G, which I guess in this way I have to create a data-set and fill it, then this dataset will be used in the report.

Before, I used to create RDLC or crystal reports with all the above, and I could run new tab from server side to display my reports; But now things are more complicated and new... So any hint is more than appreciated.

Comment: This is based on what kind of reports you want. If you want them in html format you need no plugin. A CSV should be also possible without. If you want a pdf u need at least pdf.js or something similar. If you want something special there are many commercial ones out there.

Comment: @Doomenik  thanks, I prefer a tool that can export to pdf or images, any idea?

Comment: When you say "display those reports on the browser", do you want that in html or as the pdf?

Comment: @monty no problem with that...

Comment: @H.Al What did you end up using? I'm looking for a report generator at the moment.

Comment: @jgritten I found 2 interesting tools: Stimulsoft (priced) and jsreport(free); Currently I am using jsreport; You can refer also to this link https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-aspnetcore ; Gd luck

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple idea will fix your problem. If you want with Crystal reports or SSRS:

1. Generate a new Web Form project that uses Crystal Report Viewer.
2. The new project has only two pages: Index.aspx, Report.aspx.
3. Index.aspx will receive report id and additional parameters of the report.
4. Index.aspx will open Report.aspx after internal processing.
5. Once the page Report.aspx is viewed, user can view, navigate and print the report.

If you want to use SSRS, you'll replace Crystal report.

This solution will cost you nothing except hosting the Web Form project on a server.

Hope this solution fix your problem.

Comment: I like your solution, but I have some questions. What if the report takes 10 minutes to create? Even if it takes 10 seconds, how do you display Report.aspx? In an iframe within a component?

Answer (score 0):

Al.

You need to say a lot more about your report requirements, otherwise it's hard to give a useful answer.  You should mention:

1. technologies - (you've got some of this already) - Angular and .Net
2. formats - you've mentioned HTML and PDF/images (in your  comment)
3. client-side/server-side - are you trying to generate
   the reports fully client-side (you have the data already at the
   client) or can you generate server side.  Each aspect has
   benefits and particularly server-side you have more options,
   access to more of your data (typically), access to your report
   storage, more installation/interfacing options and more
   processing power.
4. document types - what styles of documents
   are you trying to create. Textual reports, spreadsheet-style
   calculations and charts etc.
5. any other requirements you can think of (security, connectivity,    speed, pricing etc).

There are lots of reporting libraries/engines ranging from simple code-based design and build to template-based (mail-merging) styles.

I know that's not a specific answer, but I've written more about your options than you have written about your requirements.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Please check my updated question, thank you for the declaration

Comment: Hi Al.  Those updates are good.  There are indeed complexities in what you describe and hopefully you will get some good answers.   It sounds like you want PDF + IMAGE + HTML versions of the report which is a complicated set for sure.   You might need to try a few different tools to see if they can meet your requirements.  It might be you have to combine more than one tool/library to get your requirements met.

Comment: I guess I found something interesting, it's stimulsoft and it is used in server side. But I still don't know how to return it to angular and display it.

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you are trying to create a reporting engine using angular 5 and .net from server side. 
If your report is Pure HTML then it is easier. If it needs any graphs then you have to look for 3rd party libraries like Hicharts.

To render report as PDF you can use Angualar 5 server side rendering support (Universal). Also lots of opensource components are available to generate PDF from HML. so you can combine Universal and PDF renderer components and produce the PDF output
note: Hicharts supports serverside rendering

Also in agular 5 you can dynamically create object for components, so you can make report components are configurable and flexible